# How to get the values of variables in a different class

Tags: java, android

am making a class where the user gives input in few text boxes ,want to get that values and display it on another class having a text view.Can anyone show the correct way of doing it based on the laid oops principle .Please do provide examples for the reason...Thanks

P.s Just to be clear the Don’t want to start another activity by using intent want to store the data until a call is made

Answer (score 0):

use Intents

for eg.

```
Intent in =new intent(youractivity.this, your newclass.class);
intent.purExtra(key,value);
startActovity(in);
```

use this 
where value is your variable and in next activity you can receive same in your activity using

`YOURVAR= getIntent().getStringExtra(key)`;//for string if //your var is int type then typ getintextra()

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use that particular variable in so many activities then declare that variable as `static`.Do as follows,

Create a separate class,

```
public class Global
{
 private static String myString="hello";
}
```

To change `myString` value from anywhere,

`Global.myString="Hiii";`

To get the value of `myString` from anywhere,

`String str=Global.myString;`

Another way can be using `Intent` too. Do as per your need.

Hope it helps.